# Tiny Fibres/Dust Everywhere

Tags: cleaning, air-quality, dust, vacuum

I dust/clean/vacuum once a week which does make a difference to overall cleanliness/tidiness. However, even after cleaning, that very same day, there seems to be a new layer of dust/tiny fibres setting.

It's everywhere but I particularly notice it on my laptop screen, phone screen, tv screen. I'm usually at my desk during the day which is by a window and just moving or getting up unsettles it and you can see it in the sunlight.

When I look at the layer on my phone screen, they seem to be tiny fibers almost like extremely small hairs.

I'm thinking they're coming off of my clothes, in particular t-shirts which are just some cheap H&M ones.

Can anybody provide any advice or share their experience in dealing with a similar problem? I'm thinking just buy better t-shirts or perhaps get an air filter.

It's so annoying, these things are literally everywhere, you move anything, chair, pillows, cushion, towel there's a cloud of these things which come off. I've noticed black t shirts come out of the wash covered in them.

Could it be anything to do with hard water?

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Any chance of getting a picture?  Do you have a clothes dryer and if so, is it properly vented?

Comment: Is your furnace/AC blower filter getting changed regularly? You could run your furnace/blower in fan mode for a few days and hope that your filter can capture these fibers. Besides that you should find the source.

Comment: Hey JACK - picture uploaded. Seems to me like lint from clothes or some kind of microfibers from clothes. No dryer.

Comment: cleaning itself stirs up a lot of dust. get an air filter, you don't need an expensive one to handle huge (compared to alergens) particles of dust. In fact, an 80mm computer fan and a square of toilet paper make for an excellent filter.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been told that most dust in most homes comes from us -- shedding hair and skin cells, shedding fibers from our textiles, blown/stirred/drifting into corners where it can settle. My ridiculous suggestion would be to get a cat, which will make dust a given that you can ignore. ("Why do most cats have multicolored fur? So they can shed visibly on anything.")

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this issue in 2 cases homes that have hydronic or cable heating (no air flow).

I have seen this when the central air air filter is extremely dirty and has collapsed allowing dust to be circulated.

If it is from your clothes are you cleaning the lint catcher in the dryer? Is it damaged?

Just a note that when working in a clean room and particulate studies of clothes those that had the highest level of particulates were the ones that used a clothes line to dry the clothes.